# How could Monero be transmit under the purview of a hostile state actor?

Tags: network

Say Monero gets big in COUNTRY_X.

Say COUNTRY_X doesn't like that for whatever reason and decides to stop it from both being mined and propagating throughout their country.

Say COUNTRY_X cranks up their firewall specifically targeting Monero.

What happens then? Do we have any options at all?

[China is already able to block tor for example.](https://blog.torproject.org/learning-more-about-gfws-active-probing-system)

And the tor project hasn't even made a post about China [in over 2 years](https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/china) which seems to say that they are currently defeated and without any hope or suggestions as to how they might move forward.

Does this mean that a hostile state actor could effectively block any cryptocurrency of their choosing from being transmitted either outside of or within their own borders?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, given the nature of the internet, especially privacy enhancing tools like TOR or I2P networks that even if a government would try to block a specific service - users would always find one way or another to use it anyway. (See TOR bridges for example: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges)

Consider firewalling for example - how would a 'anti-crypto' state block you from using it? - blocking the crypto's RPC port? -> One could proxy it through ports 80 or 443 (http/https) so the blocking party could not easily determine whether its legit and simple web-traffic or being used for crypto transactions.
(That's what TOR relay operators often do, they advertise their TOR-Port as 80/443 so when users connect to it - their ISP/Government/Employer would need to do way more than fire-walling).

So the only thing I see happening if a government would outlaw a crypto is, that the users who are really determined will almost always be able to use it - users however would need to compromise on comfortability, ease of use and sadly (let's hope not) risk prosecution by such (imho) stupid laws.

Comment: Tor bridges are not effective inside China, however. "Generally, once a bridge is detected and blocked by the GFW, it remains blocked." is a quote from my link in the OP.